How to define a composition of operators?
If I define P[x]=D[#,x]& (derivative operator)
How can I define another operator $Q$ such that $Q(f(x))=Pf(x)+a$ (for example)?
Thanks.

P = D[#, x] &; Q = a + P[#] &

A direct nesting of function seems not to be part of Mathematica, because of the central aim to shield functions from evaluations.
So one has to introduce lots of local variables, evaluating and refunctionalize.
To avoid the overhead of symbols, copy math use of 'x' (not Mathematicas x=#, still to be used in the inner machine)
FChain[f_List] := Block[{x},
     Function @@ {{x}, Fold[( #2[#1] &), x , Reverse@f]}]

 d=FChain[{(1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] t] #&) ,Exp,( (-#^2)/(2 t)&)}]

$$\{x\}\mapsto \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 t}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{t}}$$
For practical purposes, one may include an option with simplifying or representing goals, eg. Simpify, Expand etc, to be applied before the expression is converted into a sealed function body again.

What is direct nesting of function?

The standard notation $$  f \circ g  =  f @ g$$

Why not? See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html

The Mathematica chain '@'  symbol in a@b is the prefix form of a[b], but is executed  only as the transport of values through fixed function bodies as expressions,  a  very slow  numerical construct in contrast to the  speed available by a construction of the optimized combination of two function bodies. Any function call implies argument  streamlining, standard simplification, domain checking and known result searches.  Workin by chains of functions inside a pure function goes blind.

@yarchik  Composition does not construct the composed function. It's  merely  a container of @a@.., that evaluates only with an  argument supplied. Of course the argument can be #, and then  a function can be defined by e.g.  Function@@{Compose[a,b][#]}
